# problems with node paths in prod env

Tags: node.js, path, base-path

I have my first node server app running fine on localhost, but in a digitalocean (ubuntu) environment I can't get the paths to work.

This line

```
require("./lib/dbHelper").initilize();
```

Generate this error

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/dbHelper'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/wsApp/app.js:18:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

And this line

```
let User = require("../models/User");
```

generates this error

```
Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/wsApp/routes/auth.js:5:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

I have looked here (https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) for solutions and I have tried suggestions 3, 4.2 and 6 but nothing changes the error messages.

Worth noting is that this line seems to work fine

```
app.use("/", require("./routes/auth.js"));
```

Being new to node I don't quite understand the path mappings, and it seems strange that this last one would work while the first one doesn't since they both use the dot syntax...

Comment: Add console.log('path:', __dirname + '/lib/helper'); before the require to see full path.  The __dirname is path to directory the script is in. So in your app.js __dirname should be /var/www/wsApp. I hope this helps you understand how require works.

Comment: Is a single dot equal to writing __dirname?

Comment: Since dot means *relative to current directory* and __dirname points to it then yes

Comment: What is actually *./lib/dbHelper* is it file or directory? If dir then this assumes there's index.js in there if file then you should use dbHelper.js and as pointed out in bellow answer I would recommend using lower case only to avoid any problems with case sensitivity. E.g. `db-helper.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing on a case-insensitive filesystem (OS X or Windows), you may be getting tripped up by the fact that the linux filesystem is case sensitive. Check, for example, that the "H" in "dbHelper" is really uppercase in your git repository.